how to update some value, angular signal array
list1 = signal<any[]>([]);

this.list1.update(datas => {
    datas.forEach(p => {
      p.allFee = p.attorneyFee;
    });
    return datas;
  });]

In this way, when you update a value, the value in the interface does not change. When you console.log it, the value has changed.
how to update ?
The value displayed on the web page changes

Try?

You need to create a new array reference only then it will be logged as a change on the signal, since arrays are stored as references in memory
Here I am use array de-structuring to create a new memory reference for the signal
list1 = signal<any[]>([]);

this.list1.update(datas => {
    datas.forEach(p => {
      p.allFee = p.attorneyFee;
    });
    return [ ...datas ]; // changed here!
  });

